# What's syntax if i need to enter unique id for every employee?

Tags: python

```
Emp_name = []
Emp_id = []
Emp_dep = []
num = 3
for i in range(num):
    x = input("enter the name of employees")
    Emp_name.append(x)

    i = input("enter the id of employees")
    Emp_id.append(i)

    d = input("enter the department of employees")
    Emp_dep.append(d)
```

if some user enter same id it will give him error or give him you can't do it

Answer (score 0):

When you use `for i in range(9)` the `range(9)` is actually a list that's equal to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` so instead of asking the user to enter id and check if the id is unique you can assign `i` for the id and in that way the id is unique.

example:

```
for i in range(5):
x = input("enter the name of employees")
    Emp_name.append(x)

    Emp_id.append(i)

    d = input("enter the department of employees")
    Emp_dep.append(d)

print(Emp_name)
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want the user to enter the id, and test if the id is unique you can do this with a `while` loop that will continue to ask for user id input until the id entered is unique.

Comment: How do to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use input sanitizing

```
Emp_name = []
Emp_id = []
Emp_dep = []
num = 3
for i in range(num):
    x = input("enter the name of employees")
    Emp_name.append(x)

    i = input("enter the id of employees")
    while i in Emp_id:
        i = input("Please try again, id must be unique")
    Emp_id.append(i)
    
    d = input("enter the department of employees")
    Emp_dep.append(d)
```